# Given a point $p\in M$ and a tangent vector $v \in T_p M$, is there a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $X(p)=v$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. My question is simple:

Given a point $p\in M$ and a tangent vector $v \in T_p M$, is there a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ such that $X(p)=v$?

I tried to answer this as follows:

Choose a coordinate chart $(U,\phi)=(U,x^1,...,x^n)$ about $p$. Then for each $q \in U$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_q,..., \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}|_q$ is a basis for the tangent space $T_qM$. In particular, we can write $v= \sum _i a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ where $a^i$ are constants. Define  $Y$ on $U$ by $Y=\sum _i a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. Then $Y$ is smooth on $U$ (since the coefficient functions $a^i$'s are smooth, being constant functions), and we have $Y(p)=v$. Now using the bump function, we may obtain a smooth vector field $X$, defined on $M$, which agrees with $Y$ in a neighborhood (possibly smaller than $U$) of $p$.

Is my argument fine? Also, is there a more simple approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is correct, and I think you can't simplify it any further.

By the way, the choice of bump function is pretty arbitrary, and not unique. So, maybe you should not use the article *the* for it.